# Java - Find Server in network

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I want to find my Server in my network, when I don't know the ip.
So that's the code I have, but it takes really (!) long to test all IPs:

```
for (int j = 1; j < 255; j++) {
   for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
       String iIPv4 = "192.168." + j + ".";
       try {
          Socket socket = new Socket();
          SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(iIPv4 + i, 2652 );
          socket.connect(address, 5);
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
          String fromServer;
          while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
             if (fromServer.equals("Connected to CC3000")) {
                System.out.println("CC3000 found! : " + iIPv4 + i);
                return iIPv4 + i;
             }
          }
       } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }
   }
}
```

so, whats a better way to find the server?

regards

Comment: If you know a hostname and domain of your server you can use it directly.

Comment: That is going to take ages! You are trying to perform a TCP connect to every host. What about getting your server to listen for a broadcast/multicast packet and respond (assuming local LAN - something similar to how UPnP works)? Failing that DNS?

Comment: @RomanC I know, but I want to make it dynamic.

Comment: @chrixm don't know exactly what you're meaning. can you please explain it to me how to make it  with a broadcast?

Comment: As the other commenters have said, not the best solution. That being said, since you're probably on a local LAN, you could speed things up by reducing the connection timeout to 500ms.

Comment: @Simon If you configure your server to listen on a Multicast address (224.0.0.x) on a specific UDP port, then when you client wants to find the server it will send out a Multicast request to the address 224.0.0.x on port x. A Multicast is a selected broadcast, so the packet would only go to your server. You can then send a unicast packet back to the client for the client to identify the server. However, this would only work on a local LAN.

Answer (score 0):

**I think that multithreading could help you here, since you don't want to be waiting for each connection to either establish or fail.**

You can try say hundreds of sockets at once instead. Also checking that IP is reachable might save you some time.

Code below is really a naive and horrible example since there's no thread management at all, but you get the picture I hope. You should get the result much faster.

```
public static void findLanSocket(final int port, final int timeout) {
    List<Thread> pool = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int j = 1; j < 255; j++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
            final String iIPv4 = "192.168." + j + "." + i;

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("TESTING: " + iIPv4);

                    try {
                        // First check if IP is reachable at all.
                        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(iIPv4);
                        if (!ip.isReachable(timeout)) {
                            return;
                        }

                        // Address is reachable -> try connecting to socket.
                        Socket socket = new Socket();
                        SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port);
                        socket.connect(address, timeout);

                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        String fromServer;
                        while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            if (fromServer.equals("Connected to CC3000")) {
                                System.out.println("CC3000 found! : " + iIPv4);
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            });

            pool.add(thread);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    // Wait for threads to die.
    for (Thread thread : pool) {
        try {
            if (thread.isAlive()) {
                thread.join();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```