# vba search for ftp server in network

Tags: vba, ms-access, server, ftp, find

vba isue...
I need to find ftp server in wireless network, so i need to check ip addresses from let say 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.50 on ftp port 2211.
if i go with loop for each address  and  open

```
 ' Open Internet Connecion
    hOpen = InternetOpen("FTP", 1, "", vbNullString, 0)

    ' Connect to FTP
    hConnection = InternetConnect(hOpen, hostName, FTP_PORT, username, password, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, IIf(PassiveConnection, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0), 0)
```

it takes to much time.
Is there any faster way to detect where is ftp server in network
Actually I need to get files from android device (e.g. smartphone or tablet) from their ftp server turned on (only way to connect to them) which are connected to wireless LAN. But their IP address is always different. I need user friendly form which will detect their ftp server.
This question is similar to this thread: [Java - Find Server in network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082077/java-find-server-in-network) ,
but I needed it in vba 
Thanks

Comment: No. There's not.

Comment: Even the Java question you have added, does not show any better way (except for speeding it up by multithreading).

Comment: I might try and another way  if the speed is some acceptable one,

Comment: Maybe it will be enough if i get ipv4 connected to wireless, so it will reduce number of tries to hconnection open

Comment: There obviously is a better way though: `InternetConnect` is a high level API function. If you first try to establish a low-level TCP connection to probe open ports you can increase speed. Google for a port scanner. I won't be providing code, as VBA port scanners are nearly exclusively malicious. It's a great way to get your machine flagged when used on a corporate network

Comment: @ErikA While `InternetConnect` is a high level function, in this case, it will fail on the very first thing it does. So I do not think that using another API will speed the process up.